# Get all the test run details executed against test plan id

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, mtm

Is there a way I can get the test runs executed against a test plan id 
programmatically ? Also i want to get the results for say last 30 day or last X days?

To get the test case results for a particular test run, I am using below query,
*`var results = proj.TestResults.Query(string.Format("SELECT * FROM TestResult WHERE TestRunId =" + testRunId + ""));`*

Answer (score 2):

To get test runs against a test plan id:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfctc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsservername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"));
        ITestManagementService testmanagementService = tfctc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
        var teamproject = testmanagementService.GetTeamProject("teamprojectname");
        var testruns = testmanagementService.QueryTestRuns("select * From TestRun");
        List<ITestRun> testrunInPlan = new List<ITestRun>(); 
        foreach (var testrun in testruns)
        {
            if (testrun.TestPlanId==31) // in this case TestPlanId is 31
            {
                testrunInPlan.Add(testrun);
            }
        }
```

To get test case result for  a particular test run:

```
ITestCaseResultCollection testcases = testrun.QueryResults();

            foreach (ITestCaseResult testcase in testcases)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TestCase ID: " + testcase.TestCaseId);
                Console.WriteLine("TestCase Title: " + testcase.TestCaseTitle);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message: " + testcase.ErrorMessage);
            }
```

Please check this blog for the details on Test Management API: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2012/08/07/code-snippets-on-test-management-apis.aspx